# Mixamo Pro Characters in Unity 3D 3.4

Tags: unity-game-engine

Has anyone experienced any issues with using Mixamo Pro characters in Unity 3D?  Following the Mixamo directions, standard characters as well as animations work well in Unity (using the RootMotionComputer and RootMotionCharacterController scripts).  However, having no luck with getting Mixamo Pro characters to move and animate properly in Unity 3D.  Any help is welcomed.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Mike,

Getting characters to work and animate in Unity is simple. That is, getting animation play back. Getting characters to move and animate together can be a much bigger problem to solve and requires a pretty good understanding of how things work inside Unity.

Have you thought about e-mailing Mixamo for help, or sending another e-mail?

Comment: Thanks Huong!  Mixamo characters purchased through the Unity story work well (move & animate).  It's the Pro characters that is the issue.  Thanks for the suggestion ... I posted a question on the Mixamo Website.